# bash prepare file for gnuplot calculate value in second row

Tags: bash, awk, gnuplot

I want to plot box chart form file with has data already in two columns.
Catch is that second column is in hex and need be additionality multiple by some const (734)
 i.e test.dat

```
amp 0x223 
dupa 0x333
jasiu 0x4a4
halo 0xb1
```

best will be to do that in bash one liner .
I just end with this

```
cat test.dat |xargs printf '%s $(printf "scale=2; %d/734\\n" | bc)\n' |xargs -0 echo
```

but that print some things like that

```
amp $(printf "scale=2; 547/734\n" | bc)
dupa $(printf "scale=2; 819/734\n" | bc)
jasiu $(printf "scale=2; 1188/734\n" | bc)
halo $(printf "scale=2; 177/734\n" | bc)
```

and not calculating second value.
Last *echo* should do the work but is not doing , why and how to fix this ?

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example! Where is anything related to **gnuplot** ?

Comment: I made mistake in description , value have to be divided by const not multiply , and result should be with precision of two places after dot/coma

Comment: That's why always post the expected output as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -P '{printf("%s %d\n", $1, $2*734)}' file

amp 401498
dupa 601146
jasiu 871992
halo 129918
```

convert 2nd field to decimal and multiply with 734.  `-P` is for POSIX mode, may disable many other useful features, however here anything else is not needed.

Comment: Yes , it is what is in description , but I made mistake in description should be "...additionality divided by some const " additionally with precision of two places after dot/coma with is done in my script by printf "scale=2; 547/734\n" | bc. Of courese Your solution is what is currently in description and thanks for that, this is some clue

Comment: @SebastianMikulski Just change `*` to `/` and `%d` to `%.2f`

Answer (score 1):

Some late night fun...

Perl to the rescue! ;-)

```
perl -aE 'say $F[0] . " " . hex($F[1])/734' file
```

Answer (score 1):

`gnuplot` to the rescue!

```
plot "test.dat" using 0:($2/734.0):xtic(1) with boxes
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Just found out, that gnuplot parses the hex data correctly without any hacks.